# In Angular Directive, How to make callback, where the function name is in a variable in parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having parent scope with a function name defined in a variable

```
$scope.form.callback = "sayHello(msg)";
$scope.sayHello = function(msg) {
    alert('Parent says ' + msg);
};
```

parent template goes something like this:

```
<a sg-dir sg-callback="{{form.callback}}" href="">click Me</a>
```

sgDir follows:

```
someModule.directive("sgDir", function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            sgCallback: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.sgCallback({msg:'Hello world!'});
        }
    };
});
```

Now this gives error as,

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the
expression [{{form.callback}}] starting at [{form.callback}}].
```

Pl help.

**Update:**

My requirement is to have the function name in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You had syntactically mistake, which leads to a parsing error, you need to correct it like below. Instead of passing interpolated function reference instead, you need to pass actual function `sayHello` on isolated scope `attribute` with its parameter name.

`sg-callback="form.callback(msg)"` where `msg` parameter there in place, which is going to filled up by the directive when you are calling `callback` function (you already had that part `scope.sgCallback({msg:'Hello world!'})`).

```
<a sg-dir sg-callback="sayHello(msg)" href="">click Me</a>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jj3MWc6VsT3AtOkxiPcO?p=preview)

**Update**

Generally preferred way to do pass callback function to directive is using `&`, but in that you can't pass `dynamic string` which will be evaluated somehow on the directive side. For such different requirement I'll suggest suggest you kind of hacky way of doing it. Do pass `string` expression from attribute don't need and make `sgCallback` to `sgCallback: "@"`(to accept string) in directive isolated scope. Next, you will get that string passed from `sg-callback` in directive, on click of anchor you will replace `'(msg)'` part of expression with actual parameter value.

The bad thing with current implementation is, I have used `scope.$parent` here to access parent scope & executing `function` expression to evaluate against parent controller scope. If you don't have isolated scope in directive you would have directive doing like `scope.$eval` instead of `scope.$parent.$eval`.

**sgDir**

```
.directive("sgDir", function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      sgCallback: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      elem.on('click', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          var callback = attrs.sgCallback.replace('(msg)', '(\''+ "Hello World" +'\')');
          scope.$parent.$eval(callback);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mdRK4sPkcyOCWCvdfCYJ?p=preview)

Comment: It has to be `sg-callback="sayHello(msg)"`, except `sayHello(msg)` must be interpreted from variable `$scope.form.callback = "sayHello(msg)";`. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, this is standard working way. But the question is, if it is possible to derive from variable?

Comment: @StalinGino yes there is way to do it.. using `$scope.$eval(attrs.sgCallback)` but that disobey pattern, as you already have directive as isolated scope variable.. but before that may I know why you wanted pass expression as string?

Comment: reason is, callback name will be part of json definition in a framework

Comment: `$scope.$eval(attrs.sgCallback)` doesn't seems to be working. Can u pl update the Plunker?

Comment: @StalinGino adding my answer in 5 minutes

Comment: instead of doing `var callback = attrs.sgCallback.replace('(msg)', '(\''+ "Hello World" +'\')');`, having `scope.$parent.msg='Hello World';` would do. But this will polute the parent. ANyway there is no straight-forward answer. thanks.

Comment: No, that would be bad way.. if suppose parent scope variable then it will mess up